# time php/javascript that runs automatically without loading the page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Is it Possible to make a script that automatically runs even without loading the page that can update the values of the database based on the time condition? how?

Comment: You can use php as a regular script, you don't have to load a page. Combine that with `cron` and you can have your php script call the same function that gets called by your web page (or whatever updates to the DB you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job. It will automatically run depending on your settings, it can run as often as every minute or as rarely as once a year. It is totally up to you.

Usually it is easy to set up so you should not have any problems with that.

We need more details about your set up though.

Comment: can I set it up using localhost for testing it before uploading it to the host server? what are the things that i need to remember in installng cron job? please help..

Comment: @BryanGiray What is your local setup?

Comment: just the typical xampp localhost. how complicated it is to install?